# audio: Unknown audio driver `jack' audio: warning: Using timer based audio emulation while I'm trying to configure pipewire / jack with a qemu VM

Tags: audio, virtual-machine, pulseaudio, qemu, alsa

Does anyone run pipewire with their VFIO setup? I want to stop using pulseaudio but I'm having issues with the correct configuration of pipewire (and jack). My goal is to hear sounds inside the Ubuntu / ElementaryOS VM that I have created using qemu and kvm. Basically I've passed though all the devices of my graphic card (RTX 2080 ti),included the audio to the VM. When I booted the VM I've realized that there weren't any input and output sources,so I've thought to use pipewire. I've read a lot of examples and tutorials,but I get an error that I'm not able to fix. First of all,I've installed all these packages on my Ubuntu 21.04 :

```
#!/bin/sh

export PIPEWIRE_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1000"


sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipewire-debian/pipewire-upstream

sudo apt install pipewire gstreamer1.0-pipewire libspa-0.2-bluetooth libspa-0.2-jack carla pulseaudio-module-jack qjackctl pulseaudio-module-jack
```

and I've started qemu with the following parameters :

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -machine q35,accel=kvm,kernel_irqchip=on -enable-kvm -m 15986 -cpu host,kvm=off \

-smp sockets=1,cores=8,threads=2 -drive if=pflash,format=raw,unit=0,readonly,file=/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE.fd \

-drive file=myVM.qcow2,if=none,discard=on,id=drive1,format=qcow2 \

-device virtio-blk-pci,drive=drive1,id=virtio1 \

-device virtio-net-pci,netdev=mynet \

-netdev tap,id=mynet,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no,vhost=on \

-audiodev jack,id=audiovm,out.start-server=true,in.start-server=true \

-device ich9-intel-hda \

-device hda-duplex,audiodev=audiovm \

-device vfio-pci,host=0000:01:00.0 \

-device vfio-pci,host=0000:01:00.1 \

-device vfio-pci,host=0000:01:00.2 \

-device vfio-pci,host=0000:01:00.3 \


where :


01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation TU102 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:10f7] (rev a1)

# Subsystem: ZOTAC International (MCO) Ltd. TU102 High Definition Audio Controller [19da:2503]

# Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci

# Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

this is the error that I get :

**audio: Unknown audio driver `jack'audio: warning: Using timer based audio emulation**

Comment: I haven't used Pipewire, but it seems to support all of ALSA/PulseAudio/Jack. Any particular reason you need Jack, and cannot do it directly with ALSA?

Comment: because I read that pipewire solves a lot of architectural problems of alsa / pulse audio. So Why don't give space to the experimentation of new tools ? yeas,pipewire supports everything,but actually Im not able to fix the error that I get.

Comment: In distros more than a decade old, ALSA is used for all kernel drivers, and both Jack and Pulseaudio use ALSA to actually access the hardware. Jack is made for low latency, and is bound to the timer of a single audio device. So if QEMU/KVM doesn't support this detailed emulation of audio devices, and if you don't give it a real hardware device to compensate, and if you want to experiment with new tools, why don't you run Pipewire directly on ALSA? No Pulseaudio, no Jack, no error message to fix. In particular if you don't need Jack for anything.

Comment: ok. pipewire + alsa can be good. Can u tell me the right arguments to pass to qemu ? I tried a lot of combinations but none of them worked.